# IllegalStateException on ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am facing a weird problem.
I instanciate a custom ArrayAdapter on a listview.
Most of the time, everything works.

But Crashlytics logs show me the following exception :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131034300, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.myapp.ui.adapters.CommentsAdapter)]
android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren (ListView.java:1566)
android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchMove (AbsListView.java:4718)
android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent (AbsListView.java:4582)
android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:8112)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2414)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2138)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2420)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2153)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2420)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2153)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2420)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2153)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2420)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2153)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2420)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2153)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2420)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2153)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2420)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2153)
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:2252)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:2507)
android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:260)
```

This is weird because this exception happens when you change adapter content without calling notifyDataSetChanged() just after.

ArrayAdapter calls it each time you call a method to add or clear data inside.

I know that this crash may happen when notifyDatasetChanged is not called from the main thread, in my case, it is always from the main thread.

Main part of my adapter :

```
public class CommentsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserCommentShort> {

    CommentActionListener mCommentListener;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    final ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    private boolean mIsLoadMorePending = false;

    public CommentsAdapter(Context context, CommentActionListener commentListener) {
        super(context, 0);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mCommentListener = commentListener;
        mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void addAll(Collection<? extends UserCommentShort> collection, int nbComments) {
        // mNbComments = nbComments;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            addAll(collection);
        } else {
            for (final UserCommentShort userCommentShort : collection) {
                add(userCommentShort);
            }
        }
        mIsLoadMorePending = false;
    }
```

EDIT

Code of my call to populate (the @subscribe annotation is used by [otto event bus](http://square.github.io/otto/)).

```
public class CommentsFragment extends AutoRefreshFragment implements OnScrollListener {
...

    @Subscribe
    public void onDataReadyEvent(DataReadyEvent evt) {

        switch (evt.getIdApi()) {
            case DisqusThreadOperation.API_GET_DISQUS_THREAD:
            case CommunityDisqusAction.API_COMMUNITY_DISQUS_LIKE:
            case CommunityDisqusAction.API_COMMUNITY_DISQUS_DISLIKE:
            case CommunityDisqusAction.API_COMMUNITY_DISQUS_ADD_COMMENT:

                if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(mCommentsThreadIdentifier)) {
                    if (DEBUG_MODE) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onDataReadyEvent()=" + evt);
                    }
                    final BusinessDataWithDisqusThread disqusThread = CommentsUtils.getRequiredDataEvent(evt, mCommentsThreadIdentifier);

                    if (disqusThread != null) {
                        mDisqusThreadDetails = disqusThread.getDisqusThreadDetails();
                        if (mDisqusThreadDetails != null) {
                            updateCommentDrawer(mDisqusThreadDetails.getNbPosts(), disqusThread.getDisqusThreadDetails(), disqusThread.getUserComments());
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

protected void updateCommentDrawer(Integer commentCount, DisqusThreadDetails thread, UserComments userComments) {

        if (commentCount == null) {
            mTvCommentsCount.setText("");
            mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mBtnCommentsViewAll.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            if (commentCount == 0) {
                mListView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            displayData(thread, userComments);

            mBtnCommentsViewAll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mCommentsTotalCount = commentCount.intValue();

            if (mCommentsTotalCount <= 0) {
                mTvCommentsCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mTvCommentsCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                final String qtyComments = CommentsUtils.getCommentCountString(mCommentsTotalCount, getActivity());
                mTvCommentsCount.setText(qtyComments);
            }
        }

        refreshConnectionStatus();
    }

    protected void displayData(DisqusThreadDetails thread, UserComments userComments) {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(userComments.getCommentList(), thread.getNbPosts());
    }
```

Comment: post the background thread where you are populating your adapter data

Comment: I added it. Is it enough for you ?

Comment: call displayData() in the UI thread and you will be safe

Comment: As I wrote, callback is done on the main thread. Otto explains that : Since at times it may be ambiguous on which thread you are receiving callbacks, Otto provides an enforcement mechanism to ensure you are always called on the thread you desire. By default, all interaction with an instance is confined to the main thread.

Comment: try to Log.d Thread.currentTread() in displayData() method

Comment: 10-24 11:25:35.702: D/CommentsFragment(6044): Thread.currentTread()=Thread[main,5,main]

Comment: The only cause that could explain the crash (for me) is a call to onMeasure to redraw the listview, and at the same time, my callback updating content. For exemple on rotation.

Comment: your error clearly states that you are updating your adapter's data in the background thread, so there must be any other thread that you are using to change the adapter's data...

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your `displayData` method:

```
protected void displayData(DisqusThreadDetails thread, UserComments userComments) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(userComments.getCommentList(), thread.getNbPosts());
    }});
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that my fragment does not use UiThread ? I added log to see the used thread => Thread.currentTread()=Thread[main,5,main]. Most important thing, most of the time, this code works. Why the callback would run on a different thread sometimes...

Comment: Yuku, where did you see that ? I checked with Thread.currentThread() out of runOnUiThread, and inside, results are the same. And to be sure, I also checked with Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper() and it is the same in and out of runOnUiThread.